# Ruby on rails SQLite3::SQLException: too many columns on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am trying to create about ca. 50.000 columns and it shows me this error. Is it a problem with my computer-power or sqlite3 cannot accept just so much columns and that is it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow! 50.000 columns is probably to much. You should re-think your database schema and maybe flip the table 90 degrees. Is there a reason for having that many columns?

Comment: I cannot flip it . I have a table 50.000 x N, N can be 1,2 but can be as well 10.000 , it is variable.

Comment: Find Sqlite limits here: http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
row | n
- - - - -
 1  | n1
 1  | n2
 1  | n3
 2  | n1
 2  | n2
   ...
```

to prevent having a big (and probably varying by row) amount of columns in your table.